# Edit angular reactive form returns null in empty inputs

Tags: angular, null, angular-reactive-forms, edit, put

I'm building a form that updates (performs put) information.

I build the form:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      prop1: [''],
      prop2: [''],
    })
```

And I create a constant with the inputs included:

```
const dict = {
      prop1: this.form.get('input1').value,
      prop2: this.form.get('input2').value
    }
```

However, when I subscribe the information, it will also detect the input fields that are empty, and replace previous information with null.

Any ideas of how could I approach this?

**UPDATE**

I know that I can do it by iterating through the values in the form like this:

const dict = {}

```
for(const i in this.form.controls){
  let res = this.form.get(i).value
  if(res != ''){
    dict[i] = res
  }
}
```

And then subscribe the modified data (the one included in the dictionary).

But I'd like to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: Your form doesn't have "input1", "input2" fields. It does have "prop1", "prop2" fields. Do you want `this.form.get('prop1').value` etc.?

Comment: does this help ... .pipe( filter(x) => x != null ).subscribe( your subscribe code ) ... filter is an RxJS operator

Comment: You can get the form value directly, `this.form.value`

Comment: @AndrewAllen Yes. I only wrote the "inputs" (that in the html are in the formControlName) just to emphasize that these are the values that come from the form. Thus, the ones I need to check the "nullness"

Comment: @danday74 Hmm. I've tried it but it doesn't seem to work. Also, I'm not sure how to set this up as I would need to check 14 inputs. It's a form with these 14 fields and each one is related to one property (types:number).
The problem is if one of them is empty, the backend receives a null in this field, so either I check the reception and if one value is null, don't update in the backend or, if it was easier, send only the modified information through the frontend.

Comment: @danday74 Would it be a good practice to check the inputs in another variable and then store the actual modified fields into the dictionary? I know it's an extra step, but it's the only thing that seems to work so far.

Comment: Felix, when you use `const dict = {prop1: this..}`, 'dict'  get the **actual value**, but not change if you change the form, BTW Why not use simple this.form.value?